# How do I delete Stories from Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm new to Storybook and React and have installed Storybook in my Create React App project.

The Storybook installation has worked but has also installed 3 example components and stories. I would like to delete these.

However when I simply delete the components `.jsx` and story `.stories.js` files Storybook crashes and I am unable to compile it again.

I've searched through the Storybook documentation and files under `.storybook` but can't find anyway to delete them.

Would anyone know how I can remove these?

Comment: tl;dr Storybook has a habit of crashing and refusing to start again because the Node cache is messed up. Delete node_modules/.cache and try again. You should be able to delete the starter stories no problem.